# Is there any way of searching just for a range of hours everyday for the last month?

Tags: splunk

I'm trying to create a search with Splunk that will allow me to have only the results during non working ours. I mean, Splunk to filter out from the logs all the events that occur from 8am to 5am.

Currently, the query I'm using is: `earliest=-1mon` so I get all the events from last month, but I only need those events that occurred outside working hours.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably multiple ways of doing this in Splunk. Below is one. I am extracting the hour field (24 hour format) into c_time and then limiting my results to ones that are between 8p and 5a. You can specify other filters like earliest and latest to be more specific. Hope this helps.

```
... | convert timeformat="%H" ctime(_time) AS c_time | search c_time>= 20 c_time<= 05
```

-Neeraj.